# How to choose between poisson regression and zero inflated models

Tags: logistic, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression, zero-inflation

I have data on children visiting the A&E department. I want to see which variables are associated with the numbers of visits. For instance, if genetic factors are associated with more visits to A&E.

I've tried a logistic regression to compare children that go to the A&E and children that don't go. After that, I've model the number of visits (1 to 7) to a poisson regression. However, I got confused if this is the most appropriate solution.

So I tried to model a hurdle regression to the data ( 0 visits to 7 visits). The results are different between the poisson ( 1 to 7 visits) and the hurdle regression (0 to 7 visits). I'm wondering what is the most appropriate approach.

Any pointers and clarification will be most welcome.

Comment: Consider a hurdle regression model or zero-inflated poisson (or it's cousin, negative binomial) if you have inflated zeros. You should test for that first. If there isn't zero inflation, you don't need a hurdle or ZIP model.

Comment: I have more than 70% of zeros and the variance/mean is ~1.6 so I think it's appropriate a hurdle regression model or zero inflated poisson. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hurdle regression model fits both of the models you are interested in (I think). It is a two-part model where both parts can be estimated completely separately: (1) You fit a binary regression model (e.g., logistic regression) to the response of "no visitis" (= 0) vs. "at least one visit" (> 0). (2) Then, you fit a zero-truncated model to the data with response > 0.

Thus, model (1) answers the question what are the determinants of no visits vs. any visits. And (2) addresses the question what determines the number of visits given that there are any visits.

Model (1) is usually a standard logistic regression while model (2) is not a standard Poisson model because the zeros have been dropped (or "truncated"). Hence, this has to be accounted for in fitting the model.

If you are using R, then the `hurdle()` function in the `pscl` package can fit this model and the accompanying `vignette("countreg", package = "pscl")` briefly explains the theory and gives more details.

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I understood. My main confusion is especially because if I model only the visits 1 to 7 with a poisson regression I get more significant variables than with the hurdle model. And I get several errors trying to fit the hurdle model in R

Comment: Fitting a standard Poisson model to the truncated data is not appropriate (because it neglects the truncation). As for the errors, it's hard to say where these come from without further information. Possibly, you are trying to include regressors that do not vary at all on the "at least one visit" subset.

Comment: That was the main reason of my confusion. Because even if I want to know what variables can affect going several times to the A&E I cannot ignore the children that don't go. Otherwise I'm looking only at half of the data. Not sure if I'm confusing you :p thank you very much!